# Tkinter entry is not letting me type an input

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In my gui, i am changing what entries are available to the user based off an input they put in for another entry (tanknum). Ie. When the user types in 1 for tank number, a set of entries will appear for tank 1. If a user types in 5 for tank number, a set of 5 entries will appear for tanks 1-5. The entries appear as attended but I cannot type anything in the entries. It's just a blinking cursor in the box. Help! Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()

frame2=tk.Frame(
    master=window,
    borderwidth=1,
)

####FUNCTIONS####
def clearframe2():
   for widgets in frame2.winfo_children():
      widgets.destroy()
      if len(frame2.winfo_children())==0:
        return

def numtanksetpoints(event):    
    tanknum=sbrnument.get()
    if tanknum=='1':
        clearframe2()
        ####Tank Setpoints####
        #High Water Level
        hwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="High Water Level (ft)")
        hwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Top Water Level
        twllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Top Water Level (ft)")
        twlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Bottom Water Level
        bwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Bottom Water Level (ft)")
        bwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Anoxic Static Fill
        anoxstatlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Anoxic Static Fill (%)")
        anoxstatent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle
        stllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle (min)")
        stlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle Prep
        stlpreplbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle Prep (min)")
        stlprepent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #WAS time
        wasdurlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="WAS time (min)")
        wasdurent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #SBR 1 Label
        sbr1lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 1")
        sbr1lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)

        hwllbl.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        twllbl.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent1.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwllbl.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent1.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatlbl.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent1.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stllbl.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent1.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlpreplbl.grid(row=6,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent1.grid(row=6,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurlbl.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent1.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)

    if tanknum=='2':
        clearframe2()
        ####Tank Setpoints####
        #High Water Level
        hwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="High Water Level (ft)")
        hwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Top Water Level
        twllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Top Water Level (ft)")
        twlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Bottom Water Level
        bwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Bottom Water Level (ft)")
        bwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Anoxic Static Fill
        anoxstatlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Anoxic Static Fill (%)")
        anoxstatent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle
        stllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle (min)")
        stlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle Prep
        stlpreplbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle Prep (min)")
        stlprepent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #WAS time
        wasdurlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="WAS time (min)")
        wasdurent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)

        sbr1lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 1")
        sbr2lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 2")
        sbr1lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr2lbl.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)

        hwllbl.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent2.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        twllbl.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent1.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent2.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwllbl.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent1.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent2.grid(row=3,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatlbl.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent1.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent2.grid(row=4,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        stllbl.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent1.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent2.grid(row=5,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlpreplbl.grid(row=6,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent1.grid(row=6,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent2.grid(row=6,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurlbl.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent1.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent2.grid(row=7,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)

    if tanknum=='3':
        clearframe2()
        ####Tank Setpoints####
        #High Water Level
        hwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="High Water Level (ft)")
        hwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Top Water Level
        twllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Top Water Level (ft)")
        twlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Bottom Water Level
        bwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Bottom Water Level (ft)")
        bwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Anoxic Static Fill
        anoxstatlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Anoxic Static Fill (%)")
        anoxstatent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle
        stllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle (min)")
        stlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle Prep
        stlpreplbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle Prep (min)")
        stlprepent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #WAS time
        wasdurlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="WAS time (min)")
        wasdurent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)

        sbr1lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 1")
        sbr2lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 2")
        sbr3lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 3")
        sbr1lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr2lbl.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr3lbl.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)

        hwllbl.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent2.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent3.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        twllbl.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent1.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent2.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent3.grid(row=2,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwllbl.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent1.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent2.grid(row=3,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent3.grid(row=3,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatlbl.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent1.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent2.grid(row=4,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent3.grid(row=4,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        stllbl.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent1.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent2.grid(row=5,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent3.grid(row=5,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlpreplbl.grid(row=6,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent1.grid(row=6,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent2.grid(row=6,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent3.grid(row=6,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurlbl.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent1.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent2.grid(row=7,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent3.grid(row=7,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)

    if tanknum=='4':
        clearframe2()
        ####Tank Setpoints####
        #High Water Level
        hwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="High Water Level (ft)")
        hwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Top Water Level
        twllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Top Water Level (ft)")
        twlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Bottom Water Level
        bwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Bottom Water Level (ft)")
        bwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Anoxic Static Fill
        anoxstatlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Anoxic Static Fill (%)")
        anoxstatent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle
        stllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle (min)")
        stlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle Prep
        stlpreplbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle Prep (min)")
        stlprepent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #WAS time
        wasdurlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="WAS time (min)")
        wasdurent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)

        sbr1lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 1")
        sbr2lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 2")
        sbr3lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 3")
        sbr4lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 4")
        sbr1lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr2lbl.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr3lbl.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr4lbl.grid(row=0,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)

        hwllbl.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent2.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent3.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent4.grid(row=1,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        twllbl.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent1.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent2.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent3.grid(row=2,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent4.grid(row=2,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwllbl.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent1.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent2.grid(row=3,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent3.grid(row=3,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent4.grid(row=3,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatlbl.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent1.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent2.grid(row=4,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent3.grid(row=4,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent4.grid(row=4,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        stllbl.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent1.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent2.grid(row=5,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent3.grid(row=5,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent4.grid(row=5,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlpreplbl.grid(row=6,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent1.grid(row=6,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent2.grid(row=6,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent3.grid(row=6,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent4.grid(row=6,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurlbl.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent1.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent2.grid(row=7,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent3.grid(row=7,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent4.grid(row=7,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)

    if tanknum=='5':
        clearframe2()
        ####Tank Setpoints####
        #High Water Level
        hwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="High Water Level (ft)")
        hwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        hwlent5=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Top Water Level
        twllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Top Water Level (ft)")
        twlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        twlent5=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Bottom Water Level
        bwllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Bottom Water Level (ft)")
        bwlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        bwlent5=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Anoxic Static Fill
        anoxstatlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Anoxic Static Fill (%)")
        anoxstatent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        anoxstatent5=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle
        stllbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle (min)")
        stlent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlent5=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #Settle Prep
        stlpreplbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="Settle Prep (min)")
        stlprepent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        stlprepent5=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        #WAS time
        wasdurlbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="WAS time (min)")
        wasdurent1=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent2=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent3=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent4=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)
        wasdurent5=tk.Entry(master=frame2,width=5)

        sbr1lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 1")
        sbr2lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 2")
        sbr3lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 3")
        sbr4lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 4")
        sbr5lbl=tk.Label(master=frame2,text="SBR 5")
        sbr1lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr2lbl.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr3lbl.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr4lbl.grid(row=0,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        sbr5lbl.grid(row=0,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)

        hwllbl.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent2.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent3.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent4.grid(row=1,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        hwlent5.grid(row=1,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)
        twllbl.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent1.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent2.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent3.grid(row=2,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent4.grid(row=2,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        twlent5.grid(row=2,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwllbl.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent1.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent2.grid(row=3,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent3.grid(row=3,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent4.grid(row=3,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        bwlent5.grid(row=3,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatlbl.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent1.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent2.grid(row=4,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent3.grid(row=4,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent4.grid(row=4,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        anoxstatent5.grid(row=4,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)
        stllbl.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent1.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent2.grid(row=5,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent3.grid(row=5,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent4.grid(row=5,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlent5.grid(row=5,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlpreplbl.grid(row=6,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent1.grid(row=6,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent2.grid(row=6,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent3.grid(row=6,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent4.grid(row=6,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        stlprepent5.grid(row=6,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurlbl.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent1.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent2.grid(row=7,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent3.grid(row=7,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent4.grid(row=7,column=4,padx=5, pady=5)
        wasdurent5.grid(row=7,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)

window.bind("<Key>",numtanksetpoints)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve] by removing widgets that aren't strictly necessary for reproducing the problem. I find it hard to believe we need more than 100 entry widgets and 50 label widgets to reproduce this. Also, when I run this code I get a blank window. When I press any key I get an error. Are you certain that _this_ code reproduces your problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).